# Echarts height not adapted，there is empty in top and bottom

Tags: css, canvas, echarts

I set a fix height 200 to a line chart and set a background color, but the actual height seems only half, i don`t set title and legend and tooltips, what take the empty place, I just want the content full the height. how can i solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please provide reproducible code for community members to inspect or help. Use Codepen/JsFiddle/CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should change grid options.
Such as..

```
    grid: {
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: '1%',
            bottom: '22%',
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
        }
```